# Are there alternatives to the 'Paths and Symbols' tabs 'Includes' and 'Symbols' in Eclipse CDT, when using Subclipse?

Tags: eclipse-cdt, subclipse, indexer

I have successfully been using the options in 'Paths and Symbols' to get the indexer to be able to recognize things in C standard library which comes from the compiler directory, for example stdint's `uint8_t`.
But now when I use the Subclipse plug-in the possibilities to do these changes are gone. The 'Properties' selection on a project has very few options, none of them related to what I am interested in here.

How to solve this? I am open to all suggestions.

I am using: Eclipse CDT 8.1.0 (Juno) and Subclipse 1.8.16

Comment: I will answer it myself, Remember to checkout a project as a 'C Project', then all options are there.